# Gridview and gridlines of android application

Tags: android

I am using `GridView` in android application also displaying data from sqlite database to `GridView`, now my problem is, data has been displayed but I am not able to show grid lines in `GridView`, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the vertical and horizontal spacing for your Gridview to, say 1dp or 2dp depending on how thick you want the border to be. Then just set the background color of your GridView to the color you need for your borders.